# Uploading tones on a synthesizer.

Tags: synthesizer

I own yamaha psr S550b and a yamaha psr 295 synths. Lately I've been composing music using fl studio and now I want to perform live using sounds (tones) from fl studio. However I was wondering if I could upload tones on my synth itself and play them directly through synth than connecting laptop.. 
So my questions are -
Is it possible to upload tones (sounds) from laptop to my synth? How? 
What softwares are available with I could do that (and synth if I would need to buy a new one just in case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Yamaha page with technical specs for the s550b it looks like you won't be able to upload your own sounds.

For this a device needs flash memory that is fast enough (=expensive) so when you press the key (or even multiple keys) the sounds feels like it is played instantly. This is usually only available in high class models and only some middle class models. Some offer the possibility to add flash memory (for example the Yamaha MOXF) and some have it by default (e.g. the Yamaha Motif series).

The keywords you want to look up are "using own samples" or "waveforms" by the way.

But the psr s550 does not seem to have any possiblity to get additional sounds.

Source: offical Yamaha site (in German)
http://de.yamaha.com/de/products/musical-instruments/keyboards/digitalkeyboards/arranger_workstations/psr-s550/?mode=model

Comment: Your comment was really helpful. Can I know of there are and synths exclusive for what I had asked for in original post? or some relatively less expensive? (other companies might do good as well for me)

Comment: It depends a bit on how exactly your use case looks like. Generally what you are asking for is called a sampler. You take samples with some recording device (of musical instruments or noises, or whatever) and then prepare those to be used as a voice in a sample based synth.
Does it have to be in Hardware? Otherwise you can use a software sample player on your computer, which should be a lot cheaper than buying a dedicated machine. I think there are even some free ones, like sfz player or Independance Sampler Workstation.

Comment: Looks like that's what I'm gonna land on for now due to lack of funds.. But thanks for the info :)

Comment: The Casio XW-G1 has the ability to load user samples. Look out for limitations though.